# Compile error getting class with getClass()

Tags: java, class, boolean, javadoc

I'm learning about `getClass` and how it works.

I read that: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

but i don't really understand why that fails:

```
boolean b;
Class c = b.getClass();
```

Can anyone explain to me why it gives me an error?

Comment: `b.class` probably works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boolean b;` is a primitive datatype and you cannot invoke methods on it using the **.** operator , Try `Boolean b`; [Boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) is the wrapper class for primitive `boolean`.

Try this:

```
Boolean b = null;
Class c = b.getClass();
```

Or better

```
Boolean b = null;
Class<? extends Boolean>  c = b.getClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `b` is of type `boolean`, which is a primitive type. Primitive types are no objects, and as such, you cannot get their class.

Answer (score 0):

Because `boolean`s are not Objects. Can't call any method on a `boolean`

Answer (score 0):

b - is primite, you can't call getClass on it. it is not an Object

Answer (score 0):

Because your are using the primitive `boolean`. It won't happen with the object `Boolean`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot invoke getClass() method on primitive datatypes.
This will do the trick for you

```
Boolean b;//Change it to Boolean wrapper class
Class c = b.getClass();
```